# Prevent select2-dropdown being detached on close to animate it

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I saw many threads how to animate the select2 dropdown on opening/closing but I can't find any of working way to animate it.
I'm want to slideDown/slideUp select2 dropdown instead of just showing it basically. 
With the `select2:opening` and `select2:open` **event**, slidedown event works but doesn't on closing/close so I've tried to figured it out and I edited the core file to make the trick working but I'm aware that edit core file is a bad option.

```
$('#select').select2({
   width: "100%",
   allowClear: false
}).on('select2:opening', function () {   
   $(this).on("select2:open", function () {
       $('.select2-dropdown').slideDown(500);    
   });
 //$(this).on("select2:closing", function () {
     //e.preventDefault();
     //$('.select2-dropdown').slideUp(1000);  
 //});
});
```

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/L5fyd7os/1/)
Arround line 4327, I've replaced

```
  AttachBody.prototype._hideDropdown = function (decorated) {
   this.$dropdownContainer.detach();
  };
```

**To :**

```
  AttachBody.prototype._hideDropdown = function (decorated) {
   //this.$dropdownContainer.detach();
    var $this = this;

    $('.select2-dropdown').slideUp(500, function(){
        $this.$dropdownContainer.detach();
    })
  };
```

It work but I'm sure there is a better way to do the trick without ediding the core file.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To animate `slideDown` on dropdown opening you could use:

```
.on('select2:open', function(e) {
    $('.select2-dropdown').hide();
    setTimeout(function() {
      jQuery('.select2-dropdown').slideDown(1000);
    });
```

where you need to append the `.on` when initializing the [`select2-dropdown`](https://select2.org/dropdown).

`$('.select2-dropdown').hide();` is used to prevent dropdown from abruptly loaded and adding [`setTimeout`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) is used for animating the slideDown.

To animate `slideUp` on dropdown closing you need to use:

```
.on('select2:closing', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function() {
      jQuery('.select2-dropdown').slideUp(1000, function() {
        close();
      });
    }, 0);
```

[e.preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) is being used to prevent the default action of the event so that it will not be triggered. Which is abruptly closing. For setTimeout it's is almost the same as opening with the difference of `slideUp` instead of `slideDown` and `close();`

`$("#select").select2('destroy');` is being used to destroy the existing select which are stuck after you close that you could see in following [jsFiddle snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/0ac2oj7s/) or [@Islam Elshobokshy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9942418/islam-elshobokshy) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/54438163/3).

And `init();` is used to reinitialize your `select2-dropdown`. See the snippet for clear example:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  init();
})


function init() {
  $('#select').select2({
    width: "100%",
    allowClear: false
  }).on('select2:open', function(e) {
    $('.select2-dropdown').hide();
    setTimeout(function() {
      jQuery('.select2-dropdown').slideDown(1000);
    });
  }).on('select2:closing', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function() {
      jQuery('.select2-dropdown').slideUp(1000, function() {
        close();
      });
    }, 0);
  });
}

function close() {
  $("#select").select2('destroy');
  init();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select id="select">
 <option value="1">Value 1</option>
 <option value="1">Value 2</option>
 <option value="1">Value 3</option>
 <option value="1">Value 4</option>
 <option value="1">Value 5</option>
 <option value="1">Value 61</option>
 <option value="1">Value 7</option>
 <option value="1">Value 8</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you could do it :

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('#select').select2({
    width: "100%",
    allowClear: false
  }).on('select2:open', function(e) {
    $('.select2-dropdown').hide();
    setTimeout(function() {
      jQuery('.select2-dropdown').slideDown("slow");
    }, 0);
  }).on('select2:closing', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function(e) {
      jQuery('.select2-dropdown').slideUp("slow", function() {
        $("#select").select2('destroy').select2({
          width: "100%",
          allowClear: false
        });

      });
    }, 0);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select id="select">
  <option value="1">Value 1</option>
  <option value="1">Value 2</option>
  <option value="1">Value 3</option>
  <option value="1">Value 4</option>
  <option value="1">Value 5</option>
  <option value="1">Value 61</option>
  <option value="1">Value 7</option>
  <option value="1">Value 8</option>
</select>
```